# Why the value of textarea changes when I write an Persian character into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Well actually my problem is very tiny .. You need glasses to see it `:-)`. Ok please do the following:

1. run the code snippet
2. write `..!` into the textarea
3. then write an space after it
4. then write `س` after it
5. now as you see, the space between dots in `..!` will be changed.

Why? Again, the problem is really negligible, but it is on my nerves. Why when I set a direction to the textarea *(like `rtl`)*, the value of that textarea will be changed *(a bit)* ?

Here is my code:

```js
$("body").on('input', 'textarea', function() {
  
      var el  = $(this);
      var len = el.val().length;
  
    // declare direction of comment in textarea
    var x = /^[^a-zآ-ی]*[a-z]/i; // is ascii
   var isAscii = x.test(el.val());
 if(isAscii){
  el.css("direction", "ltr");
 } else {
  el.css("direction", "rtl");
 }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>dynamic direction</textarea>
```

By the way, to be more clear what I'm talking about, following image is a screenshot. As you see the number of dots are identical in both cases, but the second one is wider. Why?

[image]

Comment: browser rendering glitch? Does this happen in all of them, or just a specific one?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Chrome (linux).

Comment: @Vohuman, same in chrome 52 on win, nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to character encoding. When we talk about RTL the character encoding set to UNICODE which is the super set of ASCII code (alphabets + Symbols).

RTL script used for Persian, Arabic, Urdu etc.

Unicode takes more space while typing. You can read more about RTL and Unicode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)

Comment: I experienced the same problem when I worked on urdu website. Thanks